# Replace brackets from a string

Tags: c#

I have to replace all `{` and `}` brackets in a string with `[` and `]`.

*But* I have one `{` at the very start and one `}` at the very end of the string that can't change.

How would I do this in C#?

Comment: Since the position of the braces should mean nothing, you need to post the code you've used since there is a bug in your code. Have you tried just `s = s.Replace("{", "[").Replace("}", "]");` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - I think you may have misunderstood, I think op wants to replace all but the outer most brackets. To OP, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, that seems likely.

Comment: OK, does "at the very start" and "the very end" mean first and last character of the string, or does it mean the first { brace and the last } brace?

Comment: It means the very first and last occurrence of that bracket in the string.

Comment: If you're sure you have such begin/end: `'{' + text.Replace('{', '[').Replace('}', ']').Trim('[', ']') + '}'`

Comment: It would help to avoid getting incorrect answers if you were go give some examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 4):

There's probably many ways to do this, including replacing them all and replacing first/last back to original value, but here is a Regex replacement method that will replace all the braces except the first { and the last }.

You can test this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net)

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "{ a{b}c }";

    int indexOfFirstBrace = input.IndexOf('{');
    int indexOfLastBrace = input.LastIndexOf('}');

    string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[{}]", match =>
    {
        if (match.Index == indexOfFirstBrace || match.Index == indexOfLastBrace)
            return match.Value;

        if (match.Value == "{")
            return "[";
        return "]";
    });

    output.Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
{ a[b]c }
```

Here's another method that would deconstruct the string into a character array, gather up all the characters and build another string, doing the replacements character by character.

```
string output = new string(input
    .Select((c, i) =>
        i == indexOfFirstBrace || i == indexOfLastBrace ? c
            : c == '{'                                  ? '['
            : c == '}'                                  ? ']'
                                                        : c)
    .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Replace()
    {
        string before = "{{{abc}}";
        string expect = "{[[abc]}";

        string calc = '{' + before.Substring(1, before.Length - 2).Replace('{', '[').Replace('}', ']') + '}';

        Assert.AreEqual(expect, calc);
    }
```